# How do I mock a custom modified module with jest?

Tags: typescript, express, unit-testing, jestjs

To be able to have an attached database connection that follows through all of the middleware, I have overridden the type of express's Request object by including this file in my project:

```
import OracleClient from "./clients/OracleClient";
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      oracleClient: OracleClient;
    }
  }
}
```

But then in a unit test, I need to mock out the request object and override the behavior of the oracle client.

If I try to use jest.createMockFromModule like:

`let request: Request = jest.createMockFromModule<Request>("express");`

typescript won't allow me to then do something like:

```
request.oracleClient = jest.createMockFromModule<OracleClient>("../../../src/clients/OracleClient");
```

Because it doesn't recognize see the custom interface override and thus does recognize the express request object has having an oracleClient member.

I'm aware there is another way to do this by just manually declaring my own Request object, but that involves manually specifying every single one of the necessary interface elements on the Request object, of which there are over 70.

How can I mock the Request object while being able to specify the mock behavior of the methods of the oracleClient member so that I can give a return value is something tries to call request.oracleClient. during the execution of a test?